# "gzip" feature problem trying to implement rolling logger in Rust (programmatically)

Tags: rust, gzip, language-features

I've found [this page](https://medium.com/@nikmas_dev/advanced-logging-in-rust-with-log4rs-2d712bb322de). At the bottom of that page the author says he's giving a programmatic way of configuring so as to have a console logger component but also a rolling file logger component.

I'm having trouble with this line:

```
let roller = Box::new(
    FixedWindowRoller::builder()
        .base(roller_base)
        .build(roller_pattern, roller_count)
        .unwrap(),
 );
```

I get a panic with the following message: "thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: gzip compression requires the `gzip` feature'".

As a Rust newb I've so far got a vague notion about features. I thought they belonged to specific crates. But this message doesn't mention a crate. Can someone explain what I need to do?

Comment: The duplicate applied to your use case: in your `Cargo.toml`, specify the `log4rs` dependency as: `log4rs = { version = "*", features = [ "gzip" ] }`

Comment: Thanks. 'version = "*"' ... I learn another new thing!